# How to use variables in svg filter's feflood tag?

Tags: angularjs, svg, text, svg-filters

I have following code

```
<filter x="-0.1" y="-0.1" width="1.2" height="1.3" id="color_available">
          <feFlood flood-color="#306b34" result="bg" />
             <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="bg" />
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
             </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <text filter="url(#color_available)">
          <tspan>Sample text</tspan>
    </text>
```

Now I want to use dynamic color from my component.ts file
Something like

```
<filter x="-0.1" y="-0.1" width="1.2" height="1.3" id="color_available">
          <feFlood flood-color="{{bgColor}}" result="bg" />
             <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="bg" />
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
             </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <text filter="url(#color_available)">
          <tspan>Sample text</tspan>
    </text>
```

And this bgColor will have some default value assigned in component.ts file.
How can I do this in angular9?

I tried by adding method too but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After trying too many times, I got the answer by myself.

```
<filter x="-0.1" y="-0.1" width="1.2" height="1.3" id="color_available">
                    <feFlood [attr.flood-color]="bgColor" result="bg" />
                    <feMerge>
                      <feMergeNode in="bg" />
                      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
                    </feMerge>
                  </filter>
```

Just add [attr.flood-color]="bgColor" and it will take variable's value.